# RejectChanges() on DataTable removes all rows in DataGridView

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview, datatable, datasource

i have a little issue where i can't find a solution for.

i have a form that has a custom dataGridView.
this datagridView takes in a data source.
the DataSource is a Datatable that i created myself (will be replaced later by a Database DataTable).
everything displayes just fine so far.

now i have 2 buttons in my form.
one to Save, and one to Cancell.
what i want to do is when i click on cancell, i want the changes made to my datagridView go back to its original dataTable.

so far when i click on the button, it simply deletes all rows (columns stay).

here is an exemple of what i do in my code:

```
public partial class UserControlMyDataGrid : UserControl
{
    private DataTable originalDataTable;

    public UserControlRechercheDataGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        originalDataTable = new DataTable();
        originalDataTable.Columns.Add("col A", typeof(int));
        originalDataTable.Columns.Add("col B");
        originalDataTable.Columns.Add("col C", typeof(bool));
        originalDataTable.Columns.Add("col D");

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            originalDataTable.Rows.Add(j, "c" + j.ToString(), true, "test");
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = originalDataTable;
    }

private void buttonCancelModifications_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        originalDataTable.RejectChanges();
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }

}
```

anyone have any idea why it behaves this way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because all of the `RowState`'s are `Added`. You should call `AcceptChanges` after you initially populate the data table to make them `Unmodified`.

see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thank you very much. i had read the MSDN documentation and checked the rowstate but for the dattable.RejectChanges() it only talked about modified and deleted states, not the added state.
in any case. thanks again. this clarified a whole lot.
little question. i just have to do the same if i want  to save it. just accept changes and then export the datatable as i see fit ?